# SELECT group by twice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, request

I'm not strong in DB at all and I need your help.
I need SQL request with GROUP by twice.

Example of my data in table

```html
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tr><th>id</th><th>market_id</th><th>price</th><th>low</th><th>high</th><th>symbol</th><th>created_at</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>5773.8</td><td>5685</td><td>6020</td><td>btcusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:10</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0.4274</td><td>0.39</td><td>0.43983</td><td>iotusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:11</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>0.20026</td><td>0.1986</td><td>0.20352</td><td>xrpusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:12</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>5771</td><td>5685</td><td>6020</td><td>btcusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:18</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>2</td><td>0.4274</td><td>0.39</td><td>0.43983</td><td>iotusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:18</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>2</td><td>0.20026</td><td>0.1986</td><td>0.20352</td><td>xrpusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:19</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>1</td><td>5773.1</td><td>5685</td><td>6020</td><td>btcusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:25</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>1</td><td>0.4274</td><td>0.39</td><td>0.43983</td><td>iotusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:25</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>1</td><td>0.20026</td><td>0.1986</td><td>0.20352</td><td>xrpusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:26</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>5773.1</td><td>5685</td><td>6020</td><td>btcusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:32</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>2</td><td>0.42741</td><td>0.39</td><td>0.43983</td><td>iotusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:32</td></tr>
<tr><td>12</td><td>2</td><td>0.20026</td><td>0.1986</td><td>0.20352</td><td>xrpusd</td><td>2017-10-27 16:46:33</td></tr></table>
```

I would like to get latest data for every market_id and symbol
That's mean I need somethind like that in the end :

```
 - id  market_id symbol
 - 7    1        btcusd
 - 8    1        iotusd
 - 9    1        xrpusd
 - 10   2        btcusd
 - 11   2        iotusd
 - 12   2        xrpusd
```

Really need help, a little bit blocked.

Comment: Generate a derived table obtaining the max created, market_Id and symbol  grouped by market_ID and symbol, then INNER join that back to your base set to return the other needed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try this

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM CRYPTO as C
JOIN (
  SELECT market_id, symbol, MAX(id) as maxid
  FROM CRYPTO
  GROUP BY market_id, symbol
) AS C2
ON   C2.maxid = C.id and C.market_id = c2.market_id and c.symbol = c2.symbol
```

Comment: Thx Radim, yep... I was near :)

Comment: This could return incorrect results if ID is an auto number and created dates/records  are not always inserted in sequence.  if they are, then this would be fine.

Comment: @xQbert actually i did not noticed the `create_at` attribute, I thought that he needs result with highest id.

Comment: @RadimBača fair point: "I would like to get latest data" is ambiguous.  So the question remains latest data by what? ID or create_at or something else?

Comment: @AntonLytvynov It is nice, when you select one answer as a correct one ...

Answer (score 1):

Along these lines...

```
SELECT MAX(id), market_id, symbol
    FROM crypto
    GROUP BY market_id, symbol
```

Comment: Ah no, I need max(id), unique(market), unique(symbol)

Comment: Does this not accomplish this? The GROUP BY clause collapses the values into unique lines. (I've edited the fields to be appropriate)

Comment: This does return the example results provided.  But I think the question is incomplete/ambiguous.  It doesn't show how "to get latest data for every market_id and symbol".  I interpreted data to include price, low high. and the "Something like" to be an incomplete example of the results complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my comment stated as SQL.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.MarketID, A.Symbol, A.Price, A.Low, A.High
FROM CRYPTO A
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(Created_at) MCA, Market_ID, Symbol
            FROM crypto
            GROUP BY Market_ID, Symbol) B
  on A.Created_At = B.MCA
 and A.market_ID = B.Market_ID
 and A.Symbol = B.Symbol
```

What this does:

The derived table (aliased B) generates 1 line for each market_ID and symbol having the max created_at time.  It then uses this derived table set to join back to the base set (aliased A) to limit the data to just those having the max created_at.  this allows us to show the whole record from A for each unique market_Id and symbol; but only for records having the max created_at.

Other engines would allow you to use a cross apply or an analytic to obtain the desired results.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thank you very much xQbert

Answer (score 0):

I tried these requests

```
SELECT * FROM CRYPTO as C3
  JOIN (
     SELECT MAX(id) as max
     FROM CRYPTO as C1
     GROUP BY symbol
   ) AS C2
ON C2.max = C3.id

SELECT M.id, M.name, R.symbol FROM MARKET AS M
  JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT C.symbol, C.market_id
     FROM CRYPTO as C
   ) as R
ON M.id = R.market_id
```

But finally I did not find the good combination.

Comment: your first query just needs to `group by symbol, market_ID` to get the desired results provided ID is autonumber and records are entered in sequence by created_at